# Unit rules and style convention for division

Tags: convention, unit-of-measure

I'm trying to figure out the preferred way to write unit expressions and division is causing me some confusion. I'm aware of the negative exponent notation, but here I'm looking for a solution using the division sign (solidus).

The SI unit standard states that we should write "(a/b)/c, not a/b/c" (http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP330/sp330.pdf), which makes sense.
However (a/b)/c could also be expressed as a/(b·c). I have seen that in some cases for example mi/(h·s). The base unit for Volt = kg·m^2/(s^3·A^1) also follows this style as seen here: http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html. That pages also notes that "The solidus must not be repeated on the same line unless parentheses are used."

The only consistent rule I can come up with is that only one solidus should be allowed. That would mean kg·m^2/(s^3·A^1), mi/(h·s) and a/(b·c) are correct, but it does go against what the SI standard suggests with (a/b)/c.

So what do you think?

Comment: I'd write $\dfrac{a}{b\cdot c}$, if I had to choose.

Answer (score 0):

The intention of the standard is probably just that a/b/c should not be used, because it could be seen as ambiguous, not that (a/b)/c should never be written as a/(b·c).

ISO 80000-1:2009 has an example on page 23 expressing precisely this, saying

> [...] a solidus (/) shall not be followed by a multiplication sign or a
>   division sign on the same line unless parentheses are inserted to
>   avoid any ambiguity.

And by using negative exponents in units, the "problem" can of course be completely avoided, as you say: V = kg·m²·s⁻³·A⁻¹.